# VMWare Tools Stops Working upon dist-upgrade

Tags: vmware, vagrant

To give a little background, i'm trying to prepare a Vagrant environment that I will use for WordPress development. I downloaded the Precise_64 VMWare Workstation box and configured the Vagrant Plugin and can start up the VM and SSH into it with no issues. As a standard thing while working with all boxes (to mimic my production environment) I do `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` to have the latest version of core packages before I go installing other things.

At some point down the line I do a `vagrant reload` and it fails while loading the "HGFS Kernel Module" and says I cannot use shared directories without it loading. I then SSH into the machine and noticed that the VMWare Tools process is not even running. I was able to recreate this on another machine and on a new machine that the `dist-upgrade` stops VMWare Tools from loading on reboot. How can I fix this so when I start a new VM and update things I won't have to deal with this issue anymore?

Comment: Was the kernel updated? You need to run `vmware-config-tools.pl` every time a different kernel gets installed so that the drivers get rebuilt.

Comment: I assume it was. Where is the `vmware-config-tools.pl` located? @MarkPlotnick

Comment: Found it, it works now. Kind of frustrating that I have to do this after every kernel update, but thank you for your help! Can you add it as an answer so I can give you credit? @MarkPlotnick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMware tools use VMware-supplied kernel modules, generally found in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/misc/`. When a new version of the kernel is installed, the kernel modules need to be recompiled.

Running `vmware-config-tools.pl` will recompile and install them.

`vmware-config-tools.pl` is usually in `/usr/bin`, but may be in `/usr/local/bin` or elsewhere, depending on where the VMware tools package was installed.